# Use Java to intercept print jobs on machine

Tags: java, printing

I am exploring options to intercept print jobs using Java. I know this is a very complex problem to solve, but was wondering if anyone tried it. I would like to monitor print requests coming to a network printer and analyze them before they are actually submitted for print. This looks solvable using a Network monitoring tool or using low-level code, but please let me know if there are other workarounds.

Comment: My first thought would be to create a virtual printer that would be your application and then redirect the document to the printer after analyzing. All the requests would have to be sent to the virtual printer. Allegedly you can use a Java LPD implementation to create and interface a virtual printer.

Comment: But depending on what exactly you want to do, you might be better off with a print server like CUPS.